# debugger in bash

Tags: bash, debugging

I use

```
sh -xv my_script.sh
```

to debug the /bin/sh script.
How do I debug /bin/bash scripts?

I am getting the following error and I need to know the line that needs to edit.

```
# ./batch_master.sh

'@'10.10.10.10.' (using password: NO)user 'companycuser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
bash -x ./batchmaster_sh
```

Comment: It does work. But shows a lot of junk. I want to know only the mysql command that does not work. I do not see that anywhere in the output. The output is much lengthy than expected.

Comment: Well... what happens if you `grep 10.10.10.10 ./batch_master.sh` or `grep mysql ./batch_master.sh` :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the script, add a -x option to the shell command line like:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

It will print all executed commands and you can see what is done after what.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The problem got solved after running dos2unix command on the properties file.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a debugger for bash around for a since the turn of the century. See http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/

If you are going to use `set -x` tracing I recommend setting PS4 to:

```
 PS4='(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]} -  [${SHLVL},${BASH_SUBSHELL}, $?]
'
```